# mysql подстановка разных формул из таблицы в зависимости от значения

Tags: mysql

mysql. есть такая задача, не знаю как решить.
есть таблица с более чем 1000 записей. нужно посчитать длину по каждой записи по определённой формуле. эти формулы хранятся в другой таблице их может быть разное количество. в зависимости от вида продукции нужно брать соответствующую формулу и по ней высчитывать длину . то есть на выходе должен получиться уже результат в виде метров. формулы в таблице хранятся так если бы я их использовал в запросе, но только с привязкой к своим виду продукции.

я сейчас подумал что модно было бы решить с использованием php, но очень интересмно можно ли такое решить через mysql?

Comment: можно попробовать сделать функцию, которая примет на вход формулу и требуемые для вычисления параметры и выполнит вормулу через динамический запрос (см. prepare и execute)

Comment: Если количество видов продукции небольшое и статическое - можно обойтись и пухлым `CASE`.